# Js different between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

I want to find difference between two arrays, but unique. I can just find unique value in difference, but maybe there are best way to find it?
Expecred output: [ 4,  6,  7,  1 ]

```js
const first = [5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 3];
const second = [7, 3, 5, 1, 1];
let difference = first
                 .filter(x => !second.includes(x))
                 .concat(second.filter(x => !first.includes(x)));
                 alert(difference)
```

Comment: please add the wanted result to the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz added, but  there is an ansver already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const first = [5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 3];
const second = [7, 3, 5, 1, 1];
let diff = first
  .filter(x => !second.includes(x))
  .concat(second.filter(x => !first.includes(x)))
  .filter(onlyUnique);

console.log(diff);

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```